# Loop through a range changing the font colour in specific cells every time I refresh the page

Tags: excel, vba

I have written this code as a start. I think I'm on the correct path but the code obviously requires more for it to work. Essentially I want to start in cell W8:

- If the font is black in W8, it should move to W9 and through the range (W8, W9, W10, W11, W12, Y8, Y9, Y10, Y11, Y12 and then back to W8 as a loop) checking if the font is black.
- If the loop stops on a cell where the font is red, it should be changed to black and the next cell in the list should be changed to red. It should then exit the sub.

```vb
    SubFontW8()
    If Range("W8").Font.Color = vbRed Then
        Range("W8").Font.Color = xlAutomatic
    And
    Range("W9").Font.Color = vbRed
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Call SubFontW9()
    End If
    End Sub
    
    SubFontW9()
    If Range("W9").Font.Color = vbRed Then
        Range("W9").Font.Color = xlAutomatic
    And
    Range("W10").Font.Color = vbRed
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Call SubFontW10()
    End If
    End Sub
    
    SubFontW10()
    If Range("W10").Font.Color = vbRed Then
        Range("W10").Font.Color = xlAutomatic
    And
    Range("W11").Font.Color = vbRed
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Call SubFontW11()
    End If
    End Sub
    
    SubFontW11()
    If Range("W11").Font.Color = vbRed Then
        Range("W11").Font.Color = xlAutomatic
    And
    Range("W12").Font.Color = vbRed
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Call SubFontW12()
    End If
    End Sub
    
    SubFontW12()
    If Range("W12").Font.Color = vbRed Then
        Range("W12").Font.Color = xlAutomatic
    And
    Range("Y8").Font.Color = vbRed
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Call SubFontY8()
    End If
    End Sub
    
    SubFontY8()
    If Range("Y8").Font.Color = vbRed Then
        Range("Y8").Font.Color = xlAutomatic
    And
    Range("Y9").Font.Color = vbRed
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Call SubFontY9()
    End If
    End Sub
    
    SubFontY9()
    If Range("Y9").Font.Color = vbRed Then
        Range("Y9").Font.Color = xlAutomatic
    And
    Range("Y10").Font.Color = vbRed
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Call SubFontY10()
    End If
    End Sub
    
    SubFontY10()
    If Range("Y10").Font.Color = vbRed Then
        Range("Y10").Font.Color = xlAutomatic
    And
    Range("Y11").Font.Color = vbRed
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Call SubFontY11()
    End If
    End Sub
    
    SubFontY11()
    If Range("Y11").Font.Color = vbRed Then
        Range("Y11").Font.Color = xlAutomatic
    And
    Range("Y12").Font.Color = vbRed
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Call SubFontY12()
    End If
    End Sub
    
    SubFontY12()
    If Range("Y12").Font.Color = vbRed Then
        Range("Y12").Font.Color = xlAutomatic
    And
    Range("W8").Font.Color = vbRed
    Exit Sub
    Else
    Call SubFontW8()
    End If
    End Sub
```

Any help you have would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You will have to provide the community with your attempt before we can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've updated the question with my attempts.

Comment: If anyone is able to help, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I have given you an answer. Please mark it complete if it answers your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I need. I really appreciate that you have taken the time to explain it, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to complete this task. First, you will need a [For Next Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement). Within this context, you can either use a `For Next`, or a `For Each`. I suggest reading up more about loops to better your understanding.

For simplicity in your example, I am going to use a `For Each` loop.

See below code (to be inserted in any normal module in the VBE):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Change_Font_Colour()
    
    'range where you want to change the font colours
    Dim rOperationRange As Range
    'variable used to loop through the operation range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    
    'set range object
    'you should ALWAYS have a worksheet qualifier
    'change the sheet name to the required sheet name and adjust your range accordingly
    Set rOperationRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mySheetName").Range("W8:Y12")
    
    
    'for loop
    For Each cell In rOperationRange
        If cell.Font.Color = vbRed Then
            'set to black
            cell.Font.Color = vbBlack
            'set cell BELOW as red using .Offset
            cell.Offset(1, 0).Font.Color = vbRed

            'now exit
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next cell
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: @OliverRobinson you're welcome. Please mark this as the answer to close the ticket.